# References and books on the theory of trees.

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, trees, discrete-optimization

I am looking for some references that deal (even in an abstract way) about the specific theory of “trees” (as a subtopic of graph theory).

More specifically, I am looking for references about optimization among trees. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combinatorial Optimization. Theory and Algorithms, Bernhard  Korte Jens  Vygen. Maybe chapter 6 can help you